# No suitable copy constructor after capturing a class with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, copy-constructor

I had the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{public:
    Foo() {}
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    auto lambda = [=]() mutable { std::cout << foo.a; };

}
```

And things were working fine, until I needed to add a copy constructor to my Foo class:

```
Foo(Foo& t) {}
```

And it wouldn't compile anymore, giving the message:

> class 'Foo': no copy constructor available or copy constructor is
>   declared 'explicit'

I've made the lambda mutable because I didn't want capture a const Foo, but what I think is happening is that the lambda can't be copied. Another compiler had a more useful error message:

> error: use of deleted function
>   ‘main()::< lambda()>::< lambda>(main()::< lambda()>&&)’

and:

> main()::< lambda()>::< lambda>(main()::< lambda()>&&)’ is implicitly
>   deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

But I don't really understand this. Is that implicitly deleted function the move constructor of the lambda? I can't understand why just adding a copy constructor to the captured class (not the lambda) makes this happen.

This is what I picture lambda/functor as looking like:

```
class lambda
{public:

     Foo foo; // <---- My captured variable/class
     void operator()(){ std::cout << foo.a; }
}
```

So then a copy of one of these lambdas to another involves calling Foo's assignment operator or copy constructor? I don't understand how just Foo having a copy constructor makes this fail or what is "ill-formed". The other thing I noticed is that there's no problem when the lambda captures by reference [&].

Edit: It doesn't compile on this compiler:

https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++/

I'm on Visual Studio and it wouldn't compile. However when I made a much smaller example it would compiler, but still underline the error. In my larger project it doesn't compile.

Comment: Your code (with the added 'copy constructor') compiles without a peep with `MSVC` and `clang-cl` (using C++17 standard). What compiler and standard are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) prototype is `A(const A&)`. You are effectively missing the `const` qualifier on your copy constructor which is why the error happens.

Comment: I've been reading up on this, the copy constructor can be const or not, I'm pretty sure it has to be non-const if it takes ownership of a pointer or something. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor_(C++)  Edit: In my Foo copy constructor I modify the other Foo, I copy the pointer and set the other to nullptr.

Comment: @Zebrafish, copy ctor should take a const reference. Its job is to make a copy, it should **not** modify the original object.

Comment: @Evg How do I copy the pointer of the other Foo and set it to nullptr if it's const?

Comment: @Zebrafish "I copy the pointer and set the other to nullptr" sounds more like a move than a copy.

Comment: @Zebrafish, if you want to modify a pointer in the original object, use a move constructor, which takes an rvalue reference (`Obj&&`).

Comment: Why would you set the pointer of `other` to `nullptr` in the first place? As stated by @Evg a copy constructor makes a copy and doesn't touch the `other` variable.

Comment: From the cppreference page linked in this answer: *A class can have multiple copy constructors, e.g. both T::T(const T&) and T::T(T&). If some user-defined copy constructors are present, the user may still force the generation of the implicitly declared copy constructor with the keyword default.*

Answer (score 1):

```
auto lambda = [=]() mutable { std::cout << foo.a; };
```

on the right you create temporary closure. Based on this temporary closure is constructed another by calling default move constructor generated by compiler.

```
closure c(closure{});
```

default implementation of *move* constructor just moves all data members one by one:

```
struct closure {
    Foo foo;

    closure (closure&& theOther) : foo(std::move(theOther.foo))   // <--- [1]
    {}                              // binding rvalue ref to lvalue ref
};
```

your `Foo` ctor takes `Foo&`, but it is not allowed to bind *rvalue* reference to *lvalue* reference.

It works in MSVC because it has an extension to deal with such thing. Under G++/Clang it must fail.

With `const Foo&`, works fine because temporary can be bound to *const lvalue* ref.

Comment: Wow, that illustration really helped me. I have a class that holds a pointer, and when I assign one to another the new one should take ownership of the pointer. But if I make move constructor Foo(Foo&& other) then I can't go Foo foo1; Foo foo2 = foo1; because foo1 isn't rvalue. I have a function that returns a Foo like Foo foo = createNewFoo(); What should I return from that function?

Comment: In first case why not use `Foo foo2(std::move(foo1));`. Regarding the second question, function just returns `Foo`, new one instance will be constructed by move constructor, then it takes ownership of pointer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, C++ standard version plays major role here. Under C++17 the code is valid, under C++11/14 it is not. I gave an explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get a compilation error, you should compile this code under C++11 or C++14 standard. In C++17 it is valid. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/J-LP6g).

Let's consider

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(Foo&) {}
};
```

In C++17 we can write

```
auto f = Foo{};
```

But in C++11/14 this line will fail to compile. The reason is that in C++17 we have [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), and the correctness of copy constructor invocation, which would be ill-formed because `Foo&` cannot bind to a temporary `Foo{}` and `Foo(Foo&&)` is deleted, is not even checked by the compiler.

This translates directly into a lambda (rafix07's answer explains how), because it captures `Foo` by value. The lambda itself is fine. For example, you can write

```
[=] { std::cout << foo.a; };
```

But lambda's move constructor is ill-formed, and in C++11/14 it has to be well-formed for the line

```
auto lambda = [=] { std::cout << foo.a; };
```

to compile.